# How can I run a libGDX application on a non-GUI server environment?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, libgdx, server

I built a libGDX application that runs well on my PC desktop but when I try to run it on my Ubuntu server, it raises the following error:

> "LwjglApplication: Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libgdxroot/31ce78a2/liblwjgl64.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/libjawt.so: symbol awt_Unlock, version SUNWprivate_1.1 not defined in file libmawt.so with link time reference".

I know this is because my server is running in non-GUI mode. But how can I run my libGDX app in this environment?. I've heard about "libGDX headless backend". But I don't know how to use it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you do actually want a screen to appear, then you don't want the libGdx headless backend - That's mainly for unit test purposes.

Comment: I wish I can show a screen sir. But it looks like my vps doesn't allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answer my self this question for anyone who's looking for this.
First, added these two libraries in the build.gradle file:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
compile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
```

Then, I've started my libGDX as following:

```
HeadlessNativesLoader.load();
MockGraphics mockGraphics = new MockGraphics();
Gdx.graphics = mockGraphics;
HeadlessNet headlessNet = new HeadlessNet();
Gdx.net = headlessNet;
HeadlessFiles headlessFiles = new HeadlessFiles();
Gdx.files = headlessFiles;
Gdx.gl = mock(GL20.class);
HeadlessApplicationConfiguration config = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
ApplicationListener myGdxGame = EntryPoint.getHeadlessMyGdxGame(config);
```

and EntryPoint.getHeadlessMyGdxGame return an inherited of HeadlessApplication

Comment: I cannot resolve EntryPoint class.
Do you have a running example of HeadlessApplication?