# Loading assets in libgdx for JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit, libgdx

I am currently developing a game using libgdx and java. I am wanting to run some JUnit tests on some of the features of my game, however I am having difficulties loading in my assets. I have tried to implement Mockito so that I can make headless JUnit tests to see if this helped solved the problem but this has not helped. Here is the test class that I am trying to load an asset in (the asset is being loaded on line 17)

```
import com.kroy.game.FireEngine;
import com.kroy.game.Fortress;
import com.kroy.game.Tile;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(GdxTestRunner.class)
public class FireEngineTests {

    Tile testTile = new Tile();
    FireEngine testFireEngine = new FireEngine(100, 10, 10, testTile, 10, 100, "fireEngineSprite.png");
    Class ReflectionClass = FireEngine.class;

    @Test
    public void testRefillAmount() {
        testFireEngine.refillAmount(50);
        assertEquals(50, testFireEngine.getWaterAmount());
        testFireEngine.refillAmount(5000);
        assertEquals(100, testFireEngine.getWaterAmount());

    }


    @Test
    public void testCanShoot() {

    }


    @Test
    public void testDeath() {
        testFireEngine.setHealth(0);
        assertTrue(testFireEngine.isDisabled());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTakeDamage() {
        try {
            testFireEngine.setHealth(100);
            Method takeDamageReflection = ReflectionClass.getDeclaredMethod("takeDamage");
            takeDamageReflection.setAccessible(true);
            takeDamageReflection.invoke(50, takeDamageReflection);
            assertEquals(50, testFireEngine.getHealth());

            takeDamageReflection.invoke(5000, takeDamageReflection);
            assertEquals(0, testFireEngine.getHealth());

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransferTo() {
        Tile newLocation = new Tile(2,2);
        try {
            Method transferToReflection = ReflectionClass.getDeclaredMethod("transferTo");
            transferToReflection.setAccessible(true);
            transferToReflection.invoke(newLocation, transferToReflection);
            assertEquals(testTile.getInhabitant(),null);
            assertEquals(newLocation.getInhabitant(), testFireEngine);

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testShootTarget() {
        Fortress testFortress = new Fortress(1000, 10,2,testTile, "fortress1", "lavaTile.png");

        testFireEngine.shootTarget(testFortress);

        assertEquals(testFortress.getHealth(), (testFortress.getMaxHealth() - testFireEngine.getDamage()));
        assertEquals(99, testFireEngine.getWaterAmount());
    }
}
```

Here is the error message that I get for each of the tests that I try to run:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: /Users/michaelShepherd/Documents/University Work/Year 2/SEPR/Assessment 3/Septagon3/tests/assets/fireEngineSprite.png
```

The searched for file is definitely in that location specified and I have also made the assets folder the resouces root for this module, yet still the file does not load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think we are gonna need to see your `FireEngine` constructor to be able to help you

Comment: You might want to take a look at the headless backend. Here's [an answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905818/5288316) with relevant details to help you with testing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you work with textures in FireEngine class but you probably need to load and access textures through AssetManager as you usually do in game.